# Converting TIFF to numpy array

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library, tiff

I am currently working on transforming a TIFF file to a numpy array. A simple working code is

```
from PIL import Image

photo = Image.open("filename.tif")
photo.show()
```

Although I do get as an output the picture, I am getting the error

```
TIFFSetField: tempfile.tif: Unknown pseudo-tag 65538.
```

Moreover, when I try

```
data = np.array(photo)
print(data)
```

I am getting the output

```
[[[  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  ...
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  7   7   7 255]
  [  7   7   7 255]]

 [[  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  ...
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]]

 [[  5   5   5 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  ...
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]]
 ...

 [[  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  ...
  [  1   1   1 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  3   3   3 255]]

 [[  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  ...
  [ 11  11  11 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]]]
```

which I am pretty sure does not reflect the information of the image. Any ideas to what may cause this error? I would prefer if I didn't have to upload the image file.

Comment: Seems OK to me, 4 channels (RGB+alpha which is at 255 all the time). Did you check that `data.shape` gives you the sizes you expect (i.e. (height, width, 4))?

Comment: "... which I am pretty sure does not reflect the information of the image". Why? Do you know what these numbers represent?

Comment: Oh! I see! I was expected to get a 3D array not a 2D array. This baffled me because one of my files does not yield the error above and outputs a 2D array. What can be happening to that file? What do these numbers represent?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest reading the tiff image with open-cv instead as it automatically returns a `numpy.ndarray`. Here's the one-liner:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("path/to/img")
```

By default, the image is assumed to be in BGR. For grayscale images, just add a zero in the second argument: `cv2.imread("path/to/img", 0)`

Comment: No. It will be read as BGR with OpenCV, not RGB.

Comment: yeah but if possible to call `cv2.cvtColor()` method?

Answer (score 0):

You approach seems correct to me. Below is an example which works perfectly.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import PIL
In [3]: from PIL import Image

In [4]: img = Image.open('image.tif')
In [5]: img.show()

In [6]: img_arr = np.array(img)

# 2D array
In [7]: img_arr.shape
Out[7]: (44, 330)

In [8]: img_arr.dtype
Out[8]: dtype('uint8')

In [9]: img_arr
Out[9]: 
array([[  0,   1,   2, ..., 244, 245, 246],
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 244, 245, 246],
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 244, 245, 246],
       ...,
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 244, 245, 246],
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 244, 245, 246],
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 244, 245, 246]], dtype=uint8)
```

---

Alternatively, you can also use matplotlib for reading the image as in:

```
In [10]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [12]: img_ = plt.imread('image.tif')

# 3D array
In [13]: img_.shape
Out[13]: (44, 330, 4)

# PIL image read yields a 2D array instead
In [14]: img_arr.shape
Out[14]: (44, 330)

In [15]: img_.dtype
Out[15]: dtype('uint8')
```

Comment: I am however getting 3D arrays out of img_arr for most of my images. Can you imagine why?

Comment: What happened to the 3d dimension (4) with the previous method????